# Sitecore Package Designer - Items Dynamically - not working

Tags: packages, package-designer

As a measure to make sure we do not overwrite content updates made by content authors in the Production Content Management System, we create Content Packages from production to copy down to QA using the "Items Dynamically" option and a date range from the last deployment to present day.

There are a few known item name changes made on 8/4/2021, and the Updated Date field on the items confirms the item was changed. However, when I design a package via items dynamically from 07/14/21 - 09/02/21 the items that had name changes on 8/4/21 are not included in the package that is generated.

Is there anyone who can speak to the limitations of package creation for items dynamically added, and is it only optimal for specific types of changes to items in the content tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic package generation uses item Statistics to make the call if an item qualifies to be included in the package. So, if the fields there are updated, it should include it in the package.

Do you have any other criteria like name, template, or user selected?

Try the "Within the past days" filter than the date filter. The days uses the server time vs ISO time.

[image: Qualify code for the ItemDate filter]